# Difference between OTAInstall and StandardInstall in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, build, installation, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am creating a BlackBerry Application with Webwork and PhoneGap.

When I build an application it creates two directories:

> OTAInstall
>
> StandardInstall

I am wondering what is the difference between them, what are the usages of both.

Thanks..

Comment: hi i am newbiee to blackberry phonegap development...actually i am not getting success to build my application and creation of these folders...So requests you to plz provide me the link of the documentation of refer me the document which you have followed and succeeded..and If possible then plz a step by step guid..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OTA install means the installation process over the air, using the wireless network.
This folder contains cod files and jad file.
BlackBerry device opens jad-file wirelessly and installs the application via downloading it to the device memory.

Standard Install - it is about installing the application via BlackBerry Desktop Software and usb-cable connected to your computer and BlackBerry device. This folder contains cod-files and *.alx file (application description file). User runs BlackBerry Desktop Manager and specifies alx file location upon installing a new app. And BlackBerry Desktop Manager reads this file and installs all the cod files to the device memory.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating it, I have one more question, if you can help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677597/could-not-load-blackberry-webworkphonegap-application-in-blackberry-6-0-simulato