# how to work with blackberry file " StandardInstall "?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

> I had used **phonegap** to create **HTML** and **Java script** app . I used online build **phonegap** service to create my app . I did every thing well and I uploaded my files and i get the file for all devices as **windows , android** ...etc . but when i get **blackberry** file i had zip file **"StandardInstall"** have 4 files "cod , csl , cso ,alx " and i couldn't know how to work with these files and which one will run on blackberry i searched and i reached that i must run on simulator but i haven't one . so **is i can deploy it by online service or i must have simulator ? .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StandardInstall folder contains files which can be installed via BlackBerry Desktop Manager using your device connected via usb-cable to your desktop computer.

You connect your device, then select alx-file and Blackberry Desktop Manager installs all cod files described in this alx file to your device.

Here is my another answer to the question like yours:

[Difference between OTAInstall and StandardInstall in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676656/difference-between-otainstall-and-standardinstall-in-blackberry/6677754#6677754)

Moreover, you can install these files on simulator. Launch simulator (make sure your device is not connected via usb-cable). In simulator menu select Simulate - USB connection.

Then in BlackBerry Desktop Manager there will appear a virtual device that is represented via your simulator. Then select alx file in BlackBerry Desktop Manager and install your application.

Below is the file purpose described:

cod - compiled binary application file. This file has been written on the device upon installation process.

csl, cso - files, required for signing your application. Signing is required if you are using signed API and are going to use your application on actual device. If you want to run your app on simulator, signing is not necessary.

alx - application descriptor file. It is a simple xml-file, where application properties are described, and cod files also described. When you install your application via usb-cable, BlackBerry Desktop Manager asks for alx file to read its contents and install all described there cod files to the connected device.

Comment: if i want to get the file which will run on devices , as i want to send the file to users to run on their blackberry not to send StandardInstall

Comment: To send files to users send alx file with all signed cod files, listed in this alx file.